# Strange flicker when the app launches

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, apple-push-notifications

We are experiencing a strange flicker when the app launches. It is
intermittent and we are not able to reproduce the issue consistently.

Upon launch, the app shows the home screen for a few moments before
showing the app UI, creating in a weird flicker. We understand that
this info is light on details but we have no clue where we should
start looking.

Comment: What does this have to do with push notifications?

Comment: It mostly happens on launching the app via notification. @matt

Comment: Have you checked to see if something is halting the main thread?

Comment: There are many operations happening on the main thread, but what can be the best way to simulate this condition.